# Unable to compile no matter the package

Tags: undefined, control, sequence

I am a first time user and no matter how hard I try I am unable to compile the work into a PDF. To check if my work is not at fault I borrowed an example used to test Serbian output (I have a need to write in the Serbian Latin , preferebly directly with UTF-8 output and I suspected this to be the issue until I had the exact same situation with English fonts only). Here's the example .tex file and the answer I get in the terminal below:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\title{Mačak u vreći}
\author{Pero Perić}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Probni znakovi}
šđžčć ŠĐŽČĆ

\end{document}
```

And here is the output I get in Xetec (same as in Luatex)

```
     [filip@tux Latex learning]$ xetex 1.tex
     This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 
     2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xetex)
     restricted \write18 enabled.
     entering extended mode
     (./1.tex
     ! Undefined control sequence.
     l.1 \documentclass
              [utf8]{article}
     ?
```

Apologies if it's my lack of basic Google skills, but I found no answer for something like this. It also should be pointed out that no matter the documentclass or inputclass or any other command put, the output for the error in the terminal is always the Undefined control sequence.

I am using Vim as my text editor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Many thanks both for the welcome and the addendum to the solution! @Zarko

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `xelatex` rather than `xetex`. Likewise, `lualatex` instead of `luatex`.

When you run `xetex`, it loads with the plain TeX format that doesn't include the LaTeX definitions so you get the error that you encountered.

Comment: Many thanks @Don Hosek for the simple and effective answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: @ficonni no problem. Even someone like me who's been using TeX since the days of am* fonts and .pxl bitmap fonts sometimes types tex when I mean latex

Answer (score 7):

As supplement to nice @Don Hosek answer (+1).

With use of the pdfLaTeX engine, you need to declare font encoding, i.e. `T1` which support all "probne znakove":

**Edit:**

- Option [utf8] in the `\documentclass` is not defined, consequently using it you receive warning: `Unused global option(s): [utf8]`. Correctly you should write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

- LaTeX version after April 2018 [LATEX News](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews28.pdf) has default `utf8` encoding, so you can dropout `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
- The default LaTeX font encoding is OT1, the encoding of the original Computer Modern fonts, which not define letter đ (\dj), consequently in your case you receive error `Command \dj unavailable in encoding OT1` using LaTeX or pdfLaTeX compiler. Using them, this error is removed with use of `T1` input encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % <---
\title{Mačak u vreći}
\author{Pero Perić}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Probni znakovi}
šđžčć ŠĐŽČĆ

\end{document}
```

[image]

- using `XeLaTeX` and `luaLaTeX` you not need `T1` encoding.

Comment: this doesn't address the problem in the question at all, the OP would still get the same undefined `\documentclass` error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I don't know, maybe I missed the OP's problem. I tested my answer and it works, do believe that it addressed OP problem. Now I add some explanation to answer where I try to clarify my answer. See edit of answer.

Comment: the OP is running plain tex not latex, as Don explained in his answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are right. I change my answer again ...